# Laravel composite model mapping

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got some model, let's simplify it to "A", represented as table `table_a`. Every A has many properties, let's call them model "B" in `table_b`. A linked with B using pivot table table_a_b. But "A" may have few same models "B", with different sources - from api, automatically added etc. Sources represented by model "C" in table `table_c`.

So, `table_a_b` in general may have following field list:

```
a_id
b_id
c_id
```

Logically, table_a_b is NOT AN ENTITY, so in perfect situation it may not have it's own model. It is possible to map B lists for A using belongsToMany, but. While mapping Bs for A I want to join related C (not only c_id as pivot attribute) and get composite object, having object C as B attribute. Is it even possible? Maybe using B model, maybe not, in any case. Thanks a lot!